# Understanding added in API level in Android docs

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app with `minSdkVersion = 14`, `compileSdkVersion = 27` and `targetSdkVersion = 27`. Consider a field or a method which was added in API 16, for example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

If I remove the if statement I will get a warning in Android Studio saying **Field required API level 16 (current min is 14): android.view.View.#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN**.

So, if I remove the if statement from such a method or field, the result of method call will be ignored or an exception will be thrown saying method not found depending on the method called when running on devices with API less than 16. So far so good.

But if I use [Collections.unmodifiableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections#unmodifiableList) that was added in API 24 everything works fine. There is no crash on devices running API levels less than 24, there is even no lint warning as was there in the above case and I am getting the expected result. This [PR](https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android/pull/788) might be useful to confirm
that I am getting the correct result.

Also, while using `android.text.Html.fromHtml(String)` (surrounded by if-else) which was deprecated in API 24 I am getting a lint warning saying **fromHtml(String) is deprecated as of API 24**.

```
if (SDK_INT >= N) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
} else {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```

I am getting the warning in the else block. I have tried to re-run lint but I'm getting this warning.

So my question is how am I able to use **Collections.unmodifiableList** without any error and no lint warning? But getting a lint warning for **Html.fromHtml(String)** even after using if-else statement and is it possible to use **Html.fromHtml(String,int)** which was added in API 24 on devices running API 14.

I understand that added in API level X means that I will require min API level X to use that method, otherwise, I should be getting a crash or no result. Is something wrong with my understanding? How should I know which methods I can use on which API levels? Should I rely on lint warning for such cases because the official docs say added in API 24 but the method can run on a device running API 16?

I have searched SO and the official Android docs but I am unable to find the answer.

Comment: "So my question is how am I able to use Collections.unmodifiableList without any error and no lint warning?" -- quite possibly you are seeing a documentation bug. I seem to recall that method existed prior to API Level 24.

Comment: Often was wondering it myself. One thing worth noting here is that even if you build an app with compileSdkVersion below 24. the method is accessible. The implementation is a little bit different though. So perhaps some confusing in documents

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right this is a documentation bug and has been reported here https://issuetracker.google.com/37109296. I didn't search the issue tracker. :/ But what about the issue with `Html.fromHtml(String)`?

Comment: Perhaps Lint is confused by your `static` imports, which I assume is how you are getting `SDK_INT` and `N`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have replaced the `static` import with the class imports but the warning still persists even after running lint again.